# How to get the content of a text area into a js file

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am aware that tis question has been asked before however I am shit at html so I couldn't really apply the answer to my case.

Basically, I would like to get the content of what is written in the textarea in real time so it updates in realtime onto a javascript file.
main.html

```
<textarea type="text" name="keywords" cols="100" rows="100"></textarea> <br />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try a framework, for example React, Angular, Vue. Whatever fits you best.

Or:

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('myTextarea')
const currentValue = ''

function update(e) {
   currentValue = textarea.value
}

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', update)
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', update)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should do is add a "id" to the textarea so it's easily accessible using javascript.

Change the textarea to this:

```
<textarea id="userinput" type="text" name="keywords" cols="100" rows="100"></textarea> <br />
```

Create a function which updates it in realtime using ".value":

```
function save() {
    var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    var blob = new Blob([userInput], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
    saveAs(blob, "**your file name.txt**");
}
```

Now, all you need is to keep calling save when the text changes.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("userinput")
elem.addEventListener("change", save());
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I defined 'document' in my js file?

Comment: It should automatically be defined if you connect the js file to the HTML file. Just create a new js file and add the code in my answer to it. Then, go to the main.html and add this to the "<head"> : "<script src="myscripts.js"></script>" where myscript is the name of your file.

Answer (score 0):

does this helps ?

```js
window.onload = function() {
let txtar = document.querySelector('textarea');
txtar.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
console.log(txtar.value);
});
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" name="keywords" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea> <br />
```